# Can't read phone contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I got this Exception

```
12-01 12:28:42.552: E/AndroidRuntime(25581): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

When I want to use below code to read phone(sim) contacts

```
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 
         if(cursor.moveToFirst()&&cursor.getCount()>0&&cursor!=null){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
               // String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)); 
                String name      = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phone     =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                User user=new User();
                user.setFirstname(name);
                user.setPhoneNumber(phone);
                listdata.add(user);
                cla_contact.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            cursor.close();
         }
```

What's [roblem and how to solve?

Comment: Do you have permission in manifest?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />` add in your manifest.xml

Comment: yes, I added it. pay attention to colmn -1

Comment: Check `if (cur.getCount() > 0)`

Comment: I did but same exception

Comment: This is because cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER) probably returns -1

Comment: what should I do, So?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your first line of code with the following it is working for me.

```
 Cursor cursor = 
        getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                     null, null, null, null);
```

You better change the order of conditions in the 'if' loop to avoid null pointer exceptions (if in case cursor is null).

```
 if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0 && cursor.moveToFirst()){
```

Please accept the answer if it works for you. Thank you.

Comment: but shows names of contacts "UNKNOWN" what's problem?

Comment: @ali: is it showing all names as UNKNOWN or only few?

Comment: this problem is not related to question, it was another thing, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
    String name= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 
    System.out.println(contactID + "   " + name);
    }
 }
```

it will move the cursor to the first row before reading the data.

Makr as right if it works for you. :)

Comment: I checked and did this word, cursor.moveToFirst() returns true

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 
 if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
       String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
       String name      = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 

       System.out.println(contactID + "   " + name);
       }
 cursor.close();
 }
```

and also make sure you have this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: I did, gives same exception

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 
    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
            String name      = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 

          System.out.println(contactID + "   " + name);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
        cursor.close();
```